# nil:NilClass when ByeBug reports expected outcome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to access my dirts/index page, but I am getting this error shown in the picture below.
[image: first error message]

So I put a byebug in the #total_trip_miles to see what is going on:

```
class Driver < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :dirts
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  def total_trip_miles
    byebug
    collect_trip_miles.round.to_s
  end

  def average_speed
    total_distance = collect_trip_miles
    total_rate = collect_trip_seconds

    ((total_distance/total_rate)*3600).round
  end

  def collect_trip_miles
    dirts.map do |trip|
      trip.distance.to_f
    end.inject(:+)
  end

  def collect_trip_seconds
    seconds = []
    dirts.map do |trip|
      seconds << trip.change_in_time(trip.start_time, trip.end_time)
    end
    seconds.inject(:+)
  end

end
```

When I call the `collect_trip_miles.round.to_s` from byebug I get `"55"`, which is exactly what I want to pass my spec:
[image]

I call the method from `#drivers` in the `dirt/index.html.erb`:

```
<ul id="trips">
  <% drivers.each do |driver| %>
    <li>
      <article class="driver">
        <header>
          <h2><%= show_name_of(driver) %></h2>
        </header>
         <p>
          <%= "#{show_total_miles_of(driver)} Miles" %>
        </p>
        <table>
        </table>
        <footer>
        </footer>
      </article>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

And those methods are called from my `app/helpers/dirts_helper.rb`

```
module DirtsHelper
  def show_name_of(driver)
    the_driver(driver).name.capitalize
  end

  def show_total_miles_of(driver)
    the_driver(driver).total_trip_miles
  end

  def the_driver(driver)
    Driver.find(driver.first)
  end

  def drivers
    @driver_store = {}

    @drivers.each_with_index do |driver, dirts|
      @driver_store[driver.id] = driver.dirts
    end

    @driver_store
  end
end
```

And then the controller action comes from `app/controllers/dirts_controller.rb`

```
class DirtsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @drivers = Driver.all
  end
end
```

Based on what I've described and shown evidence for, is there some-super-obvious-I-should-be-ashamed-of-myself reason why my driver model's methods are blowing up in my localhost but debugging is reporting as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the mistake of not guarding against nil in my collection of drivers, some of them don't have any trip miles. So, calling #round on nothing is throwing an error but it works in ByeBug because that is just capturing one item in the collection that just so happens to have miles as well and so calling #round on the Float works.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be this?

```
 def the_driver(driver)
    Driver.find(driver.first)
 end
```

You are iterating `drivers.each do |driver|` in your view, do when you pass it into `show_total_miles_of` and then subsequently `the_driver`, you should not have to `find` it, as you are already dealing with a single instance of an object.

Comment: Perhaps. The interesting thing is, when I'm in byebug, the way it is setup is the only way that i could discover to access the #total_trip_miles. So, maybe I'm making something work that shouldn't be structured the way I have it.